# How to make datatables to handle Ajax requests?

Tags: jquery, datatables

I want datatables to handle itself the Ajax call to populate it, so I have this config:

```
$('#tabela-usuario-portal').dataTable({
"responsive": true,
"ordering": false,
"retrieve": true,
"ajax": 'usuario/pesquisaUsuario',
"lengthMenu": [5, 10, 20],
"columns": [
    { "data": "usuario" },
    { "data": "email" },
    { "data": "cpf" }
],
"language": {
    "lengthMenu": "Exibindo _MENU_ por p&aacute;gina",
    "zeroRecords": 'Nada',
    "paginate": {
        "previous": "Anterior",
        "next": "Próximo"
    }
},
"dom": 't<"tfooter"pl>'
});
```

and this HTML:

```
<table id='tabela-usuario-portal' class="tabelaGrid table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>usuario</th>
            <th>email</th>
            <th>cpf</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
</table>
```

Datables succesfully makes the ajax request, and the following is returned:

```
[{"id":22,"id_sgp":24539,"cpf":"58287467748","email":"ffa@aa.com","usuario":"terminator","cod_perfil"
:1,"situacao":"A"},{"id":30,"id_sgp":33951,"cpf":"24423229196","email":"zeze@indra.es","usuario":"tetris"
,"cod_perfil":89,"situacao":"A"},{"id":28,"id_sgp":34001,"cpf":"31155957865","email":"af@j.com","usuario"
:"zczc","cod_perfil":89,"situacao":"A"}]
```

But I'm getting an error:

> TypeError: f is undefined

I think I'm almost there, I just have to make the correct reference between data from JSON and his respective place. I already read the docs but couldn't figure it out. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: If you switch to the non-minified version of datatables.js, I think you'll see what the variable `f` actually represents.  That might provide a clue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

Add [`ajax.dataSrc`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) and set it to empty string (`''`) to match your data structure as shown below:

```
var table = $('#tabela-usuario-portal').DataTable({
    ajax: {
        url: 'usuario/pesquisaUsuario',
        dataSrc: '' 
    },
    /* ... skipped ... */
});
```

From the [`ajax.dataSrc`](http://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax.dataSrc) option description:

> Note that if your Ajax source simply returns an array of data to
>   display, rather than an object, set this parameter to be an empty
>   string.

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2j41t56o/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: i figured that out debugging the source... but anyways, you get acepted answer.